# Disable "Just My Code" Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: c#, asp.net, vscode-debugger, visual-studio-mac

After installing .NET 6.0 SDK and Visual Studio for Mac, I have been writing this Blazor Web application but every time I attach either Microsoft Edge or Google Chrome to the debugger and try to add break points for debugging. I reach a break point and Visual Studio says either ("C file not found") or if I try to "Step" Visual Studio says ("dotnet.wasm missing"). In Microsoft edge I specify the root folder and try to use the step over function in the browser and it still leads to an error

I've been elbow deep into the documentation and just can't seem to get anything to work. Ive tried pointing to .pdb, .dll, .wasm in the root debug folder using Solution Options but just can't get my debugger working. I believe it has to do with the "Just My Code" option but I cannot find it anywhere on Visual Studio Mac. Actually I have no idea and need professional help.

I've referenced these documents from Microsoft

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/specify-symbol-dot-pdb-and-source-files-in-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2022

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/debugging?view=vsmac-2019

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/debug?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio-mac#breakpoints-in-oninitializedasync-not-hit

/*
**IMAGES**

[Showing The Application build information about "Just My Code"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLeDe.png)

[Setting a Break point on "Counter"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e02Ry.png)

[After Clicking the Button "Click Me" Visual Studio opens window about source file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4vsQ.png)

[Trying to "Step Over" causes Visual Studio to open window about dotnet.wasm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQLCx.png)

[Trying to "Step Over" On Edge DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PsTv.jpg)

*/

Comment: I'm not thinking this is due to the "Just My Code" setting in Visual Studio Mac.  That feature prevents the debugger from hitting external code (stuff not written by you).  I'm not 100% certain this will work, but could you try removing the `#` in your host file path (i.e. rename `C#` to just `C` for example)? (You should generally avoid using that character for file path names).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I remade using the default VS file path, I also used the ASP.NET Core hosted option when creating the solution, and also added the option "Step into external code". When I run with debugging, console still says "Cannot find or open the .PDB file" and "Module was built without symbols" I now can run and trigger the debugger listener once, now when I "Step Over" and exit the method it now always throws the dotnet.wasm file not found. Using what you said I am now avoiding the "C file not found" error. Fixed one problem and now running into the next problem. MAC sucks